# Does acknowledgement is needed for fired azure alerts

Tags: azure, alert, monitor, azure-monitoring, iaas

If an alert is fired in azure and is it mandatory to acknowledge it to get the alert fired again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need not acknowledge to receive the subsequent alerts. I suppose you would have misconfigured the alert logic. Please check in the "Evaluation based on" section under Aggregation granularity (period), if you have configured the desired time period for the system to send alerts. If in case, you set the value to 24 hrs then you would receive only one notification or alert for every 24 hrs even though the evaluation takes place every 5 minutes[image]